# How to use Google Glass as a headset with MacBook?

Tags: macos, audio, macbook, bluetooth, google-glass

I connected my Google Glass to my MacBook via Bluetooth, and Sound Preferences shows that I can select my Glass for audio output, but doing so does nothing. Google Glass makes no sound even though music is playing (Glass does make the UI sounds though when I interact with it, just doesn't play my Mac's audio).

What else do I need to do?

**EDIT**: Here's a bunch of wishes in the Glass Community wishlist. Please kudo them so they get exposure and possibly the feature makes it to Glass.

https://www.glass-community.com/t5/Wishlist-for-Glass/Bluetooth-A2DP-aptX-and-AVRCP-Profile-on-Glass-please/idi-p/108692

https://www.glass-community.com/t5/Wishlist-for-Glass/Full-Bluetooth-audio-support/idi-p/50479

https://www.glass-community.com/t5/Wishlist-for-Glass/Bluetooth-a2dp-client-profile-on-Glass-aka-use-Glass-as-stereo/idi-p/35377

https://www.glass-community.com/t5/Wishlist-for-Glass/Stream-any-audio-to-Glass-from-phone/idi-p/90286

https://www.glass-community.com/t5/Wishlist-for-Glass/Support-for-Bluetooth-speakers-headsets/idc-p/143388#M8481

https://www.glass-community.com/t5/Wishlist-for-Glass/Stream-Music-from-iPhone-or-any-phone/idi-p/72133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glass does not currently support AD2P Audio for incoming bluetooth connections, so it won't play music or any audio coming from your mac (same for any other bluetooth devices)

Comment: Oh. I thought it was interesting that it shows up as an audio device though. I wonder if there's any third party apps i can sideload to enable it.

Comment: I'm currently using this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxistar.monobluetoothfreewhich only ouputs mono sound from my android phone to glass (very useful to listen to audiobooks at work and other places)

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks like there's a new link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxistar.monobluetoothfree